# Django Models (dynamic?)

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am just starting Django Website;

I have deciced to go with a model (with SQLite DB), which have the following properties:

```py
class Flow(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              verbose_name="Owner", default="ADMIN")

    source = models.CharField(default='HTTP', choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, editable=True, max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=" ")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Creation date")
```

I want to add others fields to this model depending on the source field value.

For example if the source field : 'File' is selected. I will create additionnal field (like file name, file directory ...) If 'Http' is selected, I will create a field URL.
Thus depending on the source field, I will have differents field and type.

I have read this kind of model is difficult to reprensent in Django; I am open minded to other kind of solution. My idea was to created as many model as the possible source value.

Comment: If you really want to dive into dynamic models then here is the link https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels .Please check if it helps.

Comment: You probably rather want to create all those fields by default and allow them to be null; or you should create a second model which just holds an arbitrary name and value with a foreign key to `Flow`, i.e. a one-to-many value storage.

Comment: I'd also research the form builder type packages that are available as these may be useful depending on what you're doing with dynamic data. https://pypi.org/project/django-form-builder/

Answer (score 3):

Even if you can create dynamic field in Django, you can't create dynamic column in Sqlite table `FLOW`.

If you plan to use same types of fields in different cases, you can create field with abstract name, for example `path`. That can be as URL as local file path.

In common way you need to create all columns for all choices for DB table.

```py
class Flow(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                              verbose_name="Owner", default="ADMIN")

    source = models.CharField(default='HTTP', choices=SOURCE_CHOICES, editable=True, max_length=12)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=" ")
    date = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name="Creation date")
    local_path = models.ImageField(upload_to='files', null=True, blank=True) # when source is file
    url = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True) # when source is http
```

So `local_path` may be empty when you using `HTTP` source.

Inside view you can dynamically get (or set) value through serializer:

```py
class FlowSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    path = serializers.SerializerMethodField(method_name='get_path_value')

    class Meta:
        model = Flow
        fields = ('owner', 'source', 'name', 'date', 'path')

    def get_path_value(self, instance):
        if instance.source == 'HTTP':
            return instance.url
        else:
            return instance.local_path
```

So `path` will be different for different sources.
And maybe you will be need to install django rest framework for this solution.

EDIT1:
answering to question

> So if I understand well, the best pratices should be to create 'blank'
> columns

You definitely must to describe all columns in table (unless you using non Sql-like DB, such as MongoDB). So yes, create 'blank' columns, is only one possible way.

But you can override `save` method in model, for dynamically save fields:

```py
class Flow(models.Model):
  temp_path = None
  path = models...
  url = models...
  choice = models...
  
  def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if choice == 'HTTP':
      self.url = temp_path
    else:
      self.path = temp_path
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Code above is just a quick idea. Not really working code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
So if I understand well, the best pratices should be to create 'blank' columns. Is it still the best practics, knowing that I want user to do POST request with the help of forms to create "flow"?

Comment: added `EDIT1` to answer your question

Comment: regarding your question you just deleted: have a look at https://commandlinefu.com

Answer (score 0):

You could implement a custom model field type for that, it helps you save a union object ***in one column in database***. The raw type in database could be a JSON string or other serialized types, for the model field's usage, it's just a python native object!

Here is a piece of sample code: the main jobs are these two methods:

```
class HandField(models.Field):
    # ...

    def from_db_value(self, value, expression, connection):
        if value is None:
            return value
        return parse_hand(value)

    def to_python(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, Hand):
            return value

        if value is None:
            return value

        return parse_hand(value)
```

Check the [official docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-model-fields/) for details.