# How To Implement Dynamic Columns in Django models based on POST request

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, dynamic-columns

I have created a Django RestFramework with few models like Offers, Dailysubs and Requisitions to which I need add columns dynamically for a POST request.

There should be 1-10 blank columns for a model and a Master table which has fields to configure the new column like name and other properties.

I also need to implement an approach to add these dynamic columns into serializers.

```
class Requisition(models.Model):
    skill = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    superClass = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    jobFamily = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    yearOfExp = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    grade = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
    ...
```

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    businessGroup = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sNo = models.IntegerField()
    recruiter = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manager = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    dateOfOffer = models.DateField()
    dateOfJoining = models.DateField()
    ...
    ...
```

```
class MasterTable(models.Model):
    columnName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tableName = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    columnFieldType = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

I read another post related to this at [Django Models (dynamic?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64537479/django-models-dynamic) but I don't know if I should create another model to hold these blank columns or if I should add blank columns to each model.

Comment: well my understanding you can create object of other model on the base of any model post request. like if post request will hit and masterTable object will create you can manually create object of other model and give it data to access from request.data and save those object
example is that
i have 3 models name are Employee, BankInformation and EmergencyContact so when employee will create what i will do i will create object of Bank and Emergency as well
currently this approach i m using in my recent project and make sure employee and other two table has 1 to 1 relationship